# Reference bit synchronization for TLB and page table

Tags: virtual-memory, page-tables

If a PTE is in the TLB, then in the page table, it is not recently accessed, does that mean when NRU replacement policy is used, it is very likely for this PTE to be replaced? Or is there any kind of mechanism that synchronizes the reference bit TLB and page table?